# How to rewrite the dictionary keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary.

```py
A = {'Name//ABC': 'John', 'Age//XYZ': '20', 'Place//ABC': 'Washington'}
```

I want to eliminate the unwanted information for the keys and want a clean dictionary as shown below:

```py
A = {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '20', 'Place': 'Washington'}
```

Is there a way to do this ? Can anyone help me with the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Once we have the rule that tells us how to make the new key from the old one:

```
def clean(key):
    return key.partition('//')[0]
```

Then we can simply apply a dict comprehension:

```
A = {clean(k): v for k, v in A.items()}
```

Comment: partition? (why not split?) ..and do you get both k and v when iterating over A that way?

Comment: Fixed. I always make that mistake x.x I use `partition` as a stylistic choice, because conceptually I am interested in what is on one "side" of the `//` delimiter, rather than thinking of it as the first of a series of pieces.